# JTabbedPane not working with JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

For Java GUI homework extra credit, I am trying to add a couple of Panels to a JTabbedPane. Actually, they were JFrames, but I just changed to extend JPanel instead of JFrame and removed the main(). Anyway, the when I run the main(),the JTabbedPane, and both panels show up, but separate. What am I missing?

```
   import javax.swing.*;

public class TabbedPane extends JFrame
{

    JPanel DayGui = new JPanel();
    JPanel OfficeAreaCalculator = new JPanel();
    JLabel firstLabel = new JLabel("First tabbed pane");
    JLabel secondLabel = new JLabel("Second tabbed pane");
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

    // constructor
    public TabbedPane()
    {
        DayGui.add(firstLabel);
        OfficeAreaCalculator.add(secondLabel);

        tabbedPane.add("First Panel", DayGui);
        tabbedPane.add("Second Panel", OfficeAreaCalculator);
        add(tabbedPane);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TabbedPane tab = new TabbedPane();
        tab.pack();
        tab.setVisible(true);
        JTabbedPane DayGui = new JTabbedPane();
        JTabbedPane OfficeAreaCalculator = new JTabbedPane();
        DayGui dg = new DayGui();
        OfficeAreaCalculator oac = new OfficeAreaCalculator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating 2 pairs of variables for referencing components to add to the `JFrame` but adding the ones that point to blank `JPanels`. Study this code based on the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/compile.html)

```
public class TabbedPaneApp {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTabbedPane firstPanel = new JTabbedPane();
        JTabbedPane secondPanel = new JTabbedPane();

        JLabel firstLabel = new JLabel("First tabbed pane");
        JLabel secondLabel = new JLabel("Second tabbed pane");

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane() {
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(500, 400);
            };
        };

        firstPanel.add(firstLabel);
        secondPanel.add(secondLabel);

        tabbedPane.add("First Panel", firstPanel);
        tabbedPane.add("Second Panel", secondPanel);
        frame.add(tabbedPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding. I thought I followed what you are saying but I'm not. I changed the JPanels in the TabbedPane class to
 `JPanel DayGui = new JPanel();`
 `JPanel OfficeAreaCalculator = new JPanel();`
I also changed the references in the TabbedPane() constructor, and set the main method entries to:
`  JTabbedPane DayGui = new JTabbedPane();`
  `JTabbedPane OfficeAreaCalculator = new` `JTabbedPane();`
  `DayGui dg = new DayGui();`
  `OfficeAreaCalculator oac = new OfficeAreaCalculator();`

I'm still getting the same result, 3 windows: A JTabbedPane window with 2 tabs, and the two panels

Comment: Your code has many issues. Study the example above and and follow Java naming conventions :)